# Bootstrap adding margins to left and right automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do you remove the margins and padding on the body when you use Bootstrap? I want my elements to be right against the edges of the screen but bootstrap is centering them.

Comment: Any example of code you are using? Classes you are using which produce this problem? The bootstrap scaffolding creating a gutter for padding between cols. You can configure the bootstrap options using there customizer - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the container-fluid class?

```
<div class="container-fluid">...</div>
```

See documentation here -> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Answer (score 0):

- You can customize your Bootstrap version from here , if you want : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
- You can overwrite the css-body in this way : body{...} (add this css after import the boostrap css)